# Expresssion to match the Neo4j node that satisfies two or more relations (AND) relation

Tags: neo4j

[image]I need an expression to match the Neo4j node that satisfies two or more relations. I've tried the following:

```
MATCH (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2),
      (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e:en{name:'GREY2'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) 
RETURN a

MATCH (p)--(a)--(e) 
WHERE (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) AND
      (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e:en{name:'GREY2'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) 
RETURN a
```

but I am getting no nodes returned, both the match statements work individually

[HOW TO CALL RED2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the following response:

```
MATCH (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e1:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2),
      (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e2:en{name:'GREY2'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) 
      RETURN a
```

here is the flow:

from G1 node to GREY1 and GREY2 by relation HAS, now that you have reached those nodes any RED2 node that has WITH relationship with GREY1 and GREY2 will be returned as a.

if you need to preserve the relationship of G1 with RED2, you must include TO relationship too in the query.

so your query should be:

```
  `MATCH (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e1:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2),
  (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e2:en{name:'GREY2'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2), 
  (P:pm{name:'G1'})-[:TO]->(a:RED2)
  RETURN a`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the same variable name `e` for different nodes. Try this:

```
MATCH (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e1:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2),
      (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e2:en{name:'GREY2'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) 
RETURN a
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting the response right for MATCH (e1:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2),(e2:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) return a,  once i add p:pm{name:'G1'}) node i am not getting the response, is there any condition that the match query demands a flow from one nod eto the other, i used :TO relation to address

Comment: @aalimsha the query in your comment is using 'GREY1' in both cases, when it should be one each of 'GREY1' and 'GREY2'. Fix that and it should work.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake as i posted, MATCH (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e1:en{name:'GREY1'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2),
      (p:pm{name: 'G1'})-[:HAS]->(e2:en{name:'GREY2'})-[:WITH]-(a:RED2) 
RETURN a    i tried this query, and i am getting two RED2 nodes one is not connected to G1. what could be wrong?

Comment: @aalimsha I think that you need to show us an example of data in the form of a `cypher query` for testing.